# Multiple React sites on the same Azure storage account

Tags: reactjs, azure, url-rewriting, azure-storage, azure-cdn

There is a need to improve our CI/CD process for our React application. The bottom line is:

- any commit to any git branch except release branches and master should trigger build/deploy process to Azure storage account that is currently configures as Static site and linked with CDN endpoint (Microsoft Standard).
- the deployment destination should be *{rootUrl}/{branchName}*

So we want to have multiple React applications on the same storage account/CDN endpoint. This would allow our QA team to test features independently.

I already made the following changes in the app that allows the app to work using relative path on localhost:

1. set **homepage** property in package.json

```
"homepage": "http://localhost:3001/testApp"
```

2. set **basename** attribute of Router

```
  <Router basename={process.env.RELATIVE_ROOT_URL} {...props}>
...
```

3). add a line to the .env file:

```
RELATIVE_ROOT_URL=/testApp
```

But I don't have any idea how to change URL rewrite rule for CDN endpoint to allow to open URLs like *{rootUrl}/{branchName}/somepath/* directly.

P.S. Currently we have the following rule that works well for a single site per CDN endpoint:

**Condition**:

- If URL file extension
- *Operator*: Not greater than
- *Extension*: 0
- *Case transform*: No

**Action**:

- Then URL rewrite
- *Source pattern*: /
- *Destination*: /index.html
- *Preserve unmatched path*: No

Comment: did you have a chance to try my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

1. Add `"homepage": ".",` to your package.json as it is mentioned [here](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/#serving-the-same-build-from-different-paths).
2. Change `Router` to `HashRouter` and remove the `basename` attribute.

[Here](https://www.normuradov.com/product/book-shelves/index.html#/) is my example from this [repo](https://github.com/pharrukh/react-bookshelf).
I deploy using the following command:

```
az storage blob upload-batch \
  --account-name $(AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT) \
  --account-key $(AZURE_STORAGE_KEY) \
  -s ./build/. \
  -d '$web/product/book-shelves'
```